# Adding my own description attribute to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, metadata, dataframe, pandas

I am retrieving some web data, parsing it, and storing the output as a Pandas DataFrame into an HDF5 file. Right before I write the `DataFrame` into the H5 file, I add my own description string to annotate some metadata about where the data came from and whether anything went wrong while parsing it.

```
In [1]: my_data_frame.desc = "Some string about the data"

In [2]: my_data_frame.desc

Out[1]: "Some string about the data"

In [3]: print type(my_data_frame)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

However, after loading the same data with `pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore()`, my added `desc` attribute is missing and I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'desc'` as if I had never added this new attribute.

How can I get my metadata descriptions to persist as an extra attribute of the DataFrame object? (Or is there some existing, recognized attribute of a DataFrame that I can hijack for my metadata purposes?)

Comment: I realize this question is eight years old, but I answered a different question that might apply to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/64324510/5666087

Answer (score 6):

Adding DataFrame metadata or per-column metadata is on the roadmap but hasn't been implemented yet. I'm open to ideas about what the API should look like, though.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible just to overwrite the `__doc__` attribute, or is it bound for a DataFrame? I am finding that when I try to overwrite it, and then load the object from H5, the docstring is actually just `None`. It doesn't keep my new docstring, but also doesn't revert to the regular docstring.

Comment: Further, a simple workaround for me would be to write a dictionary to the H5 file, with a 'data' key for the DataFrame and a 'description' key for my string description. But this gives a Key Error. Is this an error with H5py/PyTables? Surely you ought to be able to store non-rectangular data arrays to H5?

Comment: Sorry, in re-reading that it may have come off sounding critical. I did not mean you (or Pandas) specifically, but rather HDF5. I'm assuming it can accommodate a dictionary, but perhaps the PyTables HDFStore being used is unique to a pandas object?

Comment: I would also really like some simple custom attribute capability. I am working with astronomical spectra and a DataFrame is a fantastic toool to store them, but it would be very nice to be able to write a tag like the redshift of the object (without having to write an entire extra column for that).

Comment: Perhaps the column metadata api can look similar to the [netCDF4 attributes](https://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html) api.

Comment: For those interested: The issue is discussed in issue 2485 "Allow custom metadata to be attached to panel/df/series?" here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2485