# Python Dataframe Adding a description to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a description to a column like the source of data from where I collected this. Is such thing is possible? There was a similar question asked about 8 years ago at [Adding my own description attribute to a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672403/adding-my-own-description-attribute-to-a-pandas-dataframe) with no answer.

My code:

```
df=
     
index            colA          colB
#description     from SensorA   SensorB   # Description row 
1
2
3
```

Comment: The simplest solution I can think would be to set the `.name` attribute for each column individually, for example `df['colA'].name='from SensorA'`, or is a requirement for an answer that the attribute has to use it's own custom attribute?

Comment: @G.Anderson With that will we able to save it? I mean like we save the data frame as csv or excel file ?

Comment: If you want the description to be written to a file in the format shown above, you could also just add it as a multiindex in the columns, e.g. `df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.columns,['from SensorA', 'SensorB']))`. Then it's always visible as an additional column header, and can be written to file as such. Much less sophisticated than the answers below, but effective IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment on [pandas-dev/pandas#2485](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2485#issuecomment-608227532) suggests using `_metadata` and `.attrs`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#define-original-properties for more information.

One way to do this is to subclass `pandas.DataFrame` and add `_metadata`.

> Define `_metadata` for normal properties which will be passed to manipulation results.

```
import pandas as pd

class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    # normal properties
    _metadata = ['description']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame

data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [10, 12, 13]}

df = SubclassedDataFrame(data)

df.description = "About my data"
```

Setting `_metadata` in the subclass indicates that these properties should be propagated after manipulation. See the example using `.head()` below for a demonstration of the difference between `pd.DataFrame` and this subclass.

```
data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [10, 12, 13]}

df = SubclassedDataFrame(data)
df.description = "About my data"
df.head().description  # prints 'About my data'

df_orig = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_orig.description = "About my data"
df_orig.head().description  # raises AttributeError
```

Comment: a good idea!, but it can not save by txt with the dataset in harddisk.