# Adding a description to a Pandas DataFrame column as an attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes, metadata

I would like to a add a description of each column in my DataFrame as a per-column attribute. To recap what's on SO, there was a similar question asked about 8 years ago at [Adding my own description attribute to a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672403/adding-my-own-description-attribute-to-a-pandas-dataframe) with no answer. More recently, this question was asked again at [Python Dataframe Adding a description to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324469/python-dataframe-adding-a-description-to-column) and received an answer that uses `_metadata` and `.attrs`. However, the answer seems to be geared to dataframe-level attributes, not column-level ones. Setting column-level attributes with that approach does not propagate those properties after manipulation. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd

class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    # normal properties
    _metadata = ['description']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame

data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [10, 12, 13]}

df = SubclassedDataFrame(data)

df.description = "About my data"
df['a'].description = 'column a description'
```

Results:

```
df.description   # prints 'About my data'
df.head().description   # prints 'About my data' after manipulation
df['a'].description   # prints 'column a description'
df['a'].head().description   # **raises AttributeError**
```

How can I set column-level attributes that persist after manipulation? I apologise if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't exist. The reason why is because when you call something like `head()` on a `df`, it actually generates a _new_ data frame in the background. That frame just happens to contain just the top of your original data frame.

Comment: @ifly6 thanks, but if so, why would the dataframe-level custom attribute persist, as shown in the second result of my question? The new DataFrame is clearly retaining the DataFrame-level `.description` attribute. According to the answer to the second question I linked, _'Setting _metadata in the subclass indicates that these properties should be propagated after manipulation.'_ Why wouldn't this also work for an attribute set on a specific column?